# how to disable 7 zip from opening normal applications folders and files?

Tags: 7-zip

So I've been having trouble with my 7 zip on windows xp. I don't know what i did, but suddenly all of my normal folders,applications and files have started opening in 7 zip,even though their not zipped.It won't let my antivirus run. I've tried to uninstall 7 zip , but the add and remove program opens in 7 zip also,and shows some folders that are empty. Does anyone know how to help me fix this?

Comment: Run 7-Zip as administrator and see if .exe has been added to its list of associated programs for some reason

Comment: I've checked and .exe isn't on the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can try uninstalling a program from command prompt.

Open up cmd
product get name
product where name="7 zip" call uninstall

You may need to replace 7 zip with the actual name of the 7 zip application

Source - http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2947/windows_uninstall_application_command_line/

If it tries to open cmd with 7 zip try booting into DOS

To get cmd to not be opened with 7zip - http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2630-default-programs-set-program-s-default-associations.html

Comment: I've tried opening cmd but it opens in 7zip also. Are there any other posible ways to somehow undo all of this?

Comment: So looking around, I see that you can change each one by doing the following - You can go to the Control Panel, Default Programs. From there you can select which program opens which extension. OR http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/2630-default-programs-set-program-s-default-associations.html

I would just change the cmd back to normal so that you can get this uninstalled.

Comment: I've tried uninstalling it from the command line and it didn't u do anything. and now I've tried to open the default program but it opens up in 7 zip file manager like all the other programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can change default program file association from within Control Panel >> Default Programs. I'd recommend checking there to see if 7zip has been selected for, what sounds like, the majority of the file associations. Microsoft documentation is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#post_install).